# UDIM texture exported from Substance Painter to Blender

Tags: uv, shaders

UDIM texture exported from Substance Painter to Blender is overlapping for some parts in the mesh. The UDIM UV is working in SP, so wondering what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the settings of the UDIM tiles in the image texture settings.

[image]